# Replace right fragment with another fragment when clicked on Button in left fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment Activity in which I have 2 fragments. Left fragment hast Button and right has data to display details of the button which is clicked.When the activity is loaded the right fragment should be is blank and when any button in left fragment is clicked I want that the right fragment should be replaced with another fragment depending on the button which is clicked.
My question is How to replace the right fragment with another fragment when clicked on button in left fragment

Comment: have you searched for replacing fragments?

Comment: Tell us what have you tried?

Comment: yes,I have searched for replacing fragments but all it shows is how to replace the fragment in which button is clicked. but I want the fragment to be replaced when button in another fragment is pressed

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

**1.** Create a `public method` in your `FragmentActivity` like :

```
public void sample_method()
{
     //Replace right fragment with another fragment
     Your_Right_fragment mRigthFragment = new Your_Right_fragment();
     FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
     FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
     ft.replace(R.id.right_fragment_container, mRigthFragment);
     ft.commit();
}
```

**2.** Now call this `sample_method` from your `left fragment button's click event` :

```
//On your left fragment button click event 

{
  ((Your_Fragment_Activity_Name)getActivity()).sample_method();
}
```

This will replace the `right fragment` with another fragment from your `left fragment's button click`

Comment: I want to know what will be the code to replace right fragment.